# SegFault when using gmock

Tags: c++, ubuntu, googlemock

I am using gmock 1.6 framework to code unit test.
the unit tests exit and work fine on windows.

The goal is to run them on linux.

on Linux dev env:

- when I used eclipse CDT, the test work fine.
- but when I use command line command (cmake .. && make), I get a segmentation fault while the execution.

Software versions:

- GNU Make 4.1
- gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
- cmake 3.10.2

```
class mockClass : puclic baseClass
{
   .....
   MOCK_METHOD1(function, void(const std::shared_ptr<mmmm>));
   .....

}

TEST(testSerie1, test1)
{
   mockClass attrb;
   ......
   EXPECT_CALL(attrb, function(_)).Times(AnyNumber()); // here code crahes
    ...
}
```

ERROR:

```
Thread 2 "m_thread" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread  (LWP 20104)]
0x0123 in testing::internal::FunctionMocker<void (std::shared_ptr<mmmmmmm>)>::Invoke(std::shared_ptr<mmmmmmm>) ()
(gdb) 
(gdb) 
(gdb) backtrace 
#0  ... in testing::internal::FunctionMocker<void (std::shared_ptr<mmmmmmm>)>::Invoke(std::shared_ptr<mmmmmmm>) ()
#1  ... in MockIClass::function(std::shared_ptr<mmmmmmm>) ()
.....
.....
.....
#6  0x00007ffff72bb66f in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x00007ffff758e6db in start_thread (arg=0x7ffff664e700) at pthread_create.c:463
#8  0x00007ffff6d1688f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95
(gdb)
```

Any idea please to avoid this segmentation fault ?

Comment: You most likely have some UB somewhere, which happens to take the worst possible outcome in Eclipse runs - seemingly working. Your best bet would be to run your tests under `gdb`, which will print a (very lengthy in GTest cases, unfortunately) callstack when the issue occurs. But I'm almost sure that it's not occurring at the line you marked, because the very little code you posted above should compile and run without any errors (ignoring typos).

Comment: Thanks @Yksisarvinen, I edited the post with the gdb backtrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved when I upgraded the googlemock library version to 1.8.1.